# scrbook page numbers are only present on first page of chapters

Tags: header-footer, koma-script, page-numbering

I have to submit my thesis tomorrow and al of a suddon do not get any pagenumbers for any but the first page of the chapters. Anybody out there who can help me? I fear I do not have time to build a mwe sadly.

Preamble settings:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}    

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \LARGE
  My thesis\\
  Submitted by Louis Cypher
\end{center}

\newpage
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

My system is Debian wheezy and TeX Live 2011.

Comment: Please create a MWE (minimal working example) with the relevant packages. First of all -- Did you try `\pagestyle{headings}`

Comment: You are lucky that you are not here. Otherwise I would kiss you ;-) I would never have found that in time. Please make an answer out of your comment. I had to deactivate the `\pagestyle{empty}` by a `\pagestyle{heading}` on the next page of course

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`scrbook` defines different `pagestyle` for special pages. For example chapter.

```
\newcommand*{\titlepagestyle}{plain}
\newcommand*{\partpagestyle}{plain}
\newcommand*{\chapterpagestyle}{plain}
\newcommand*{\indexpagestyle}{plain}
```

If only page numbers are printed at chapter pages I guess you have the command `\pagestyle{empty}` somewhere in your document.

Based on this guess you can use `\pagestyle{headings}` to set the header and footer for "normal" text pages in your document.

Answer (score 1):

Generally more secure would be to use a page specific style `\thispagestyle{x}` where it applies to one page only.
For the title page, I agree with Schweinebacke.
The environment `titlepage` is preferable where the empty page style is implicitly limited to the environment

For a general example which is not the title page:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}    

\begin{document}

\chapter{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-5]

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
  \LARGE
  My thesis special page
  Submitted by Louis Cypher
\end{center}

% Starting a new page with a new chapter
\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use the `titlepage` environment for the title page. This also locally uses page style `empty` for the title page and the backside of the title page:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{lipsum}    

\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \centering
  \LARGE
  My thesis\\
  Submitted by Louis Cypher
\end{titlepage}

\chapter{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-5]
\end{document}
```

[image]